# Multiple raycasts and only two are working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I am working on an ai and I'd like to give it the distance between the player (a car) and (almost) everything else in the game (walls, middle of the street, other cars). I'm doing it with Physics.Raycast. The problem is that only DistanceToRightSideOfMOTS (MOTS: middle of the street) and DistanceToBackWall are working. This is my code:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    RequestDecision();
    RequestAction();

     // Get the distances to the walls

    // Get distance to left wall
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left), out hit, 25, 1 << 11))
    {
        DistanceToLeftWall = hit.distance / 25;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left) * hit.distance, Color.red);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToLeftWall = 1;
    }

    // Get distance to right wall
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right), out hit, 25, 1 << 12))
    {
        DistanceToRightWall = hit.distance / 25;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * hit.distance, Color.red);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToRightWall = 1;
    }

    // Get distance to front wall (it sees 2x farther because it's hard to turn on the corner)
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, 50, (1 << 11) | (1 << 12)))
    {
        DistanceToFrontWall = hit.distance / 50;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.red);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToFrontWall = 1;
    }
    // Get distance to back wall
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.back), out hit, 50, (1 << 11) | (1 << 12)))
    {
        DistanceToBackWall = hit.distance / 50;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.back) * hit.distance, Color.red);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToBackWall = 1;
    }

    //////////////////

    // Get the distance to other cars

    /////////////////

    // Get distance to left car
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left), out hit, 25, 1 << 13))
    {
        DistanceToLeftCar = hit.distance / 25;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left) * hit.distance, Color.green);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToLeftCar = 1;
    }

    // Get distance to right car
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right), out hit, 25, 1 << 13))
    {
        DistanceToRightCar = hit.distance / 25;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * hit.distance, Color.green);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToRightCar = 1;
    }

    // Get distance to front car
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, 50, 1 << 13))
    {
        DistanceToFrontCar = hit.distance / 50; // We divide the distance to normalize the input
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.green);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToFrontCar = 1;
    }
    // Get distance to back car
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.back), out hit, 50, 1 << 13))
    {
        DistanceToBackCar = hit.distance / 50;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.back) * hit.distance, Color.green);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToBackCar = 1;
    }


    //Get distances to the middle of the street


    //Get distance from the left side
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left), out hit, 10, 1 << 14))
    {
        DistanceToLeftSideOfMOTS = hit.distance / 10;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left) * hit.distance, Color.blue);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToLeftSideOfMOTS = 1;
    }
    //Get distance from the right side
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right), out hit, 10, 1 << 14))
    {
        DistanceToRightSideOfMOTS = hit.distance / 10;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * hit.distance, Color.blue);
    }
    else
    {
        DistanceToRightSideOfMOTS = 1;
    }

}
```

Other distances always return 1 even if it shouldn't. Why isn't working and how can I solve it?

Edit1: I don't know why but when I bring the car super close to the right wall, DistanceToRightWall starts working and DistanceToBackCar only works when I'm at least 15m away from a car. Is there any alternative?

Edit2: I used planes for walls and the middle of the street. When I looked in the Physics Debug Visualisation, I saw plane colliders from a side, but not from the other. I am new to unity, so maybe this could be the problem.

Edit3: I added a box collider to the middle of the street and DistanceToLeftSideOfMOTS started to work, but I tried to do it with walls but it didn't work out.

Edit4: I made the box colliders bigger and it worked. The only problem now is the cars.

Comment: Note that you use different layer masks for your different Physics.Raycast calls. Is this perhaps related yo your problem?

Comment: @elgonzo I don't think that's the problem because DistanceToRightSideOfMOTS works and DistanceToLeftSideOfMOTS doesn't work even if they both use the same layermask :(

Comment: just a tip: I would prefer to use some [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) fields to configure the layers of the rays like e.g. `public LayerMask WallLayers;`. Than you can simply select the according layers in the inspector and use it like `Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left), out hit, 25, WallLayers)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built an example scene in order to try out your code but was unable to find any issues with it. Make sure your car object is correctly orientated and the walls and cars have appropriate layers and colliders assigned to them. Unity's [Physics Debug Visualization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsDebugVisualization.html) might be of help.

[image]

Also, its a good idea try too keep a bit more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). For instance you can move all the raycast calls into a single method in order to reduce repetition. This way there are fewer places to look if something is not working:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    RequestDecision();
    RequestAction();
    UpdateWallDistances();
}

private void UpdateWallDistances()
{
    int leftWallMask = 1 << 11;
    int rightWallMask = 1 << 12;
    int wallMask = leftWallMask | rightWallMask;
    int carMask = 1 << 13;
    int middleOfStreetMask = 1 << 14;

    // Get the distances to the walls
    DistanceToLeftWall = GetDistance(Vector3.left, 25, leftWallMask, Color.red);
    DistanceToRightWall = GetDistance(Vector3.right, 25, rightWallMask, Color.red);
    DistanceToFrontWall = GetDistance(Vector3.forward, 50, wallMask, Color.red);
    DistanceToBackWall = GetDistance(Vector3.back, 50, wallMask, Color.red);

    // Get the distance to other cars
    DistanceToLeftCar = GetDistance(Vector3.left, 25, carMask, Color.green);
    DistanceToRightCar = GetDistance(Vector3.right, 25, carMask, Color.green);
    DistanceToFrontCar = GetDistance(Vector3.forward, 50, carMask, Color.green);
    DistanceToBackCar = GetDistance(Vector3.back, 50, carMask, Color.green);

    //Get distances to the middle of the street
    DistanceToLeftSideOfMOTS = GetDistance(Vector3.left, 10, middleOfStreetMask, Color.blue);
    DistanceToRightSideOfMOTS = GetDistance(Vector3.right, 10, middleOfStreetMask, Color.blue);
}

private float GetDistance(Vector3 direction, float maxDistance, int layerMask, Color debugColor)
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(direction), out hit, maxDistance, layerMask))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(direction) * hit.distance, debugColor);
        return hit.distance / maxDistance;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried you code but it does the same thing as mine. I don't think that my colliders and layermasks are the problem because DistanceToBackWall works but DistanceToFrontWall doesn't even if they have the same layermasks (and they're supposed to collide with the same things). However, I used planes for walls and the middle of the street. When I looked in the Physics Debug Visualisation, I saw plane colliders from a side, but not from the other. I'm new to unity so do you think that this could be the problem?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Make sure your car object is correctly orientated".

Comment: I mean that you must make sure that the object the script is attached to is oriented in such a way that the raycast are heading from a position and in a direction you want them to go. You can add additional debug lines to visualize where the raycasts are heading. And yes, the mesh collider of a plane will only be hit by a raycast from one side. You could add a box collider if you want the object to be hit from any side.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was with colliders and the physics debug visualization really helped me.